# Nginx redirect to landing page if no cookie

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect all traffic, except my own, to the landing page example.com/landing

I have a server block in my nginx.conf, which looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset     utf-8;

    if ($bad_referer) { 
        return 444; 
    }

    location / {
        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    if ($cookie_dev != "true") {
        return 301 http://example.com/landing/;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://app;
    }

}
```

However, I get a "This webpage has a redirect loop" error in the browser.

How would you fix this?

Comment: Some ideas from reading, without any testing. Possibly status code `301 Moved Permanently` is one of the bad ideas. Try `302`. Further, (I assume this is the vhost for `example.com`) you should exclude the landing page from the `if ($cookie_dev..` clause (add a `location /landing` and move the `if` clause into `location /`). Finally, you're aware that crawlers won't be able to access your site?